# model not being recognized

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to use a model from one app into another one's views, but Django is not recognizing it's name and giving the following error:

```
local variable 'user_status' referenced before assignment
```

This is my model:

```
class user_status(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    code = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name
```

This is my view:

```
def verifica_pgto(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        date_joined = user.date_joined.replace(tzinfo=None)
        dif  =  datetime.now() - date_joined
        try:
            user_details = UserDetails.objects.get(user=user)
            if user_details.status == 'ativo':
                params = {'user_status':'ativo'}
            else:
                params = {'user_status':'inativo'}
        except:
            # cria user details
            if dif.total_seconds() > 7:
                status = 'inativo'
                user_status = user_status.objects.get(name = 'inativo')
            else:
                status = 'ativo'
                user_status = user_status.objects.get(name = 'inativo')

            d = UserDetails(
                user = user,
                created_at = datetime.now(),
                status = user_status,            
                end_access = dt.timedelta(days=7)
            )
            d.save()
        if user_status == '':
            params = {'user_status':'ativo'}
        else:
            params = {'user_status':'inativo'}
        return params
```

This is how I'm importing the model into the views.py

```
from payments.models import *
```

I also tried this way:

```
from payments.models import *
from payments.models import user_status
```

Comment: use a different variable name `user_status` for the model object.

Comment: You need to indent the `if user_status` block in the `except` to fix the issue..

Comment: This is why it is a good idea to use camel case names for class names. In your case, UserStatus would be a better name for your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to use name of instance same as class.Try this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from payments.models import user_status

def verifica_pgto(request):
    if ....
        us = get_object_or_404(user_status)
    ......
        us.objects.get(name = 'inativo')
    ....
```

Comment: Dont use `get_object_or_404` - clearly, OP does not want to raise a 404

Comment: thanks, but now I'm getting  this error msg 'expected string or buffer'

Comment: you need to return `json.dumps(params)` - Look into the `render` method

Comment: @karthikr thanks but not really, because the error is ocurring in "d.save()" line not in "return params" line